# Windows Phone - custom sliding menu from bottom

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, slide

I want to create my own bottom menu. I create custom control and I added to MainPage to Canvas at bottom. Now I want after tap on items to slide menu up and show rest of it. I am not sure how to do it. I tried something like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <Storyboard x:Key="SlideUp">
        <DoubleAnimation x:Name="myDoubleAnimation"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="bottomMenu"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                         From="64.0" To="400.0" Duration="0:0:2"
                         />
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And I call it in BottomMenu.xaml.cs:

```
    private void HomeBarImage_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard db = this.Resources["SlideUp"] as Storyboard;
        db.Begin();
    }
```

But it doesn't do anything. It's working for opacity, width and so but not for Canvas property. I guess it has something to do with that other properties at tie to control but canvas is set in MainPage.xaml.

So what is the best way to have it working? How could I fix this? And when I tapped on something in menu how can I propagate this gesture to MainPage.xaml.cs?

Comment: what is the name of the element that you want to animate? also `Canvas` is not a property

Comment: I mean Canvas.Top property. Oh now I see that I wrongly change example but in project I have it right.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `Canvas.Top` on an element that is a direct child of a `Canvas`.  Instead, you probably want to animate one of:

- `Height`
- `MaxHeight`
- add a `RenderTransform` to your menu and animate its `Y` property